# How to zip file with password (AES) for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, passwords, zip

Is there a library which is capable of zipping file with password using AES encryption?

Found this for iOS: https://github.com/gianlucabertani/Objective-Zip

Comment: I have used ZipArchive to create zip files with password and Unzip them.   The only disadvantage is that it cannot be unzip by any other mac program. reference link : https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Is it capable of protecting the zip file with password?

Comment: yup . No other program can unzip it apart from ZipArchive :) . Difficult sometimes to debug as you need to make a program on mac OSX to unzip it :) .

Comment: Which format are they using to encrypt the file? Is there one that uses AES?

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**

updated password setting in parameters and zipfile creation method.

You can use Zip4j library http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/download.php

if you want AES Encryption also you can do with following code

```
// Initiate ZipFile object with the path/name of the zip file.
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("c:\\ZipTest\\AddFilesWithAESZipEncryption.zip");

// Build the list of files to be added in the array list
            // Objects of type File have to be added to the ArrayList
            ArrayList filesToAdd = new ArrayList();
            filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\sample.txt"));
            filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\myvideo.avi"));
            filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\mysong.mp3"));

            // Initiate Zip Parameters which define various properties
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE); // set compression method to deflate compression

 //DEFLATE_LEVEL_FASTEST     - Lowest compression level but higher speed of compression
            //DEFLATE_LEVEL_FAST        - Low compression level but higher speed of compression
            //DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL  - Optimal balance between compression level/speed
            //DEFLATE_LEVEL_MAXIMUM     - High compression level with a compromise of speed
            //DEFLATE_LEVEL_ULTRA       - Highest compression level but low speed
            parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL);

            //Set the encryption flag to true
            parameters.setEncryptFiles(true);

            //Set the encryption method to AES Zip Encryption
            parameters.setEncryptionMethod(Zip4jConstants.ENC_METHOD_AES);

            //AES_STRENGTH_128 - For both encryption and decryption
            //AES_STRENGTH_192 - For decryption only
            //AES_STRENGTH_256 - For both encryption and decryption
            //Key strength 192 cannot be used for encryption. But if a zip file already has a
            //file encrypted with key strength of 192, then Zip4j can decrypt this file
            parameters.setAesKeyStrength(Zip4jConstants.AES_STRENGTH_256);

            //set password
            parameters.setPassword("your password here");

// Now add files to the zip file
            // Note: To add a single file, the method addFile can be used
            // Note: If the zip file already exists and if this zip file is a split file
            // then this method throws an exception as Zip Format Specification does not 
            // allow updating split zip files
            zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, parameters);
```

setEncryptionMethod() sets the types to encryption you want.
and setAesKeyStrength() sets the strength of the encryption algorithm.

Comment: how to password protected existing zip file using Zip4j library in android ?

Comment: You can directly set password on ZipFile object using 'setPassword()' method

Comment: `try {
                    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(output_path);
                    zipFile.setPassword("pass");

                } catch (ZipException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
` it does not working

Comment: please post logcat so I can guide you more..

Comment: thanks, but i fixed it .

Comment: If my answer was helpful you can choose it as the correct answer, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For Android, there is a nice blog post for unzipping files here: http://blog.alutam.com/2009/10/31/reading-password-protected-zip-files-in-java/ This is implemented using 7-zip standards (actually an older form of pkware zip and not AES), so you can unzip files created from other platforms as well

However, I prefer to use this : [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/), because it already has java libs and you can simply integrate them into your Android project and since integrating it JAVA libs is quite easy, you get a real quick fix. Moreover, since this supports AES, it is more relevant to your question

Edit :
A friend of mine is using [Minizip for iOS](https://github.com/nmoinvaz/minizip) to implement zipping/unzipping for his iOS project. You can try that

FYI : We could not make zip4j and Minizip inter-operate with each other when we used passwords(zip an archive in Andropid, and unzip in iOS, and vice-versa) (we tried after reading your post, so we have spent little time till now). Do post here if you try these and make a headway in this direction

Comment: Thx for replying. Do you have any recommendation for iOS?

Comment: @user1872384 Edited my answer, please check

Comment: @user1872384 What you have posted in yuor question : Object-ve-zip for iOS, that is good as well. In fact, it is a wrapper over Minizip for iOS

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenSSL  for android https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android is required some knowing in NDK for compile library to render it (.so) , is very perfermant to use native library like open ssl to win some perfermancy

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [libzip](http://nih.at/libzip/index.html) library. It's a C library and there is [Android NDK package](https://github.com/julienr/libzip-android), so you can reuse it on iOS and Android